# randomly sampling arrays - issue with numpy.delete

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shapes, delete-row

I have 2 arrays, x_1g and x_2g. I want to randomly sample 10% of each array and remove that 10% and insert it into the other array. This means that my final and initial arrays should have the same shape, but 10% of the data is randomly sampled from the other array. I have been trying this with the code below but my arrays keep increasing in length, meaning I haven't properly deleted the sampled 10% data from each array.

```
n = len(x_1g)
n2 = round(n/10)

ints1 = np.random.choice(n, n2)

x_1_replace = x_1g[ints1,:]
x_1 = np.delete(x_1g, ints1, 0)

x_2_replace = x_2g[ints1,:]
x_2 = np.delete(x_2g, ints1, 0)
```

My arrays x_1g and x_2g have shapes (150298, 10)

```
x_1g.shape
>> (1502983, 10)

x_1_replace.shape 
>> (150298, 10)
```

so when I remove the 10% data (x_1_replace) from my original array (x_1g) I should get the array shape:

1502983-150298 = 1352685

However when I check the shape of my array x_1 I get:

```
x_1.shape
>> (1359941, 10)
```

I'm not sure what is going on here so if anyone has any suggestions please let me know!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens, is that by using `ints1 = np.random.choice(n, n2)` to generate your indices, you are choosing n2 times a number between 0 and n-1. You have no guarantee that you will generate n2 *different* numbers. You are most likely generating a certain number of duplicates. And if you  pass several times the same index position to `np.delete` it will be deleted just once. You can check this by reading the number of unique values in `ints1`:

```py
np.unique(ints1).shape
```

You'll see it is not matching n2 (in your example, you'll get `(143042,)`).

There's probably more than one way to ensure that you'll get n2 different indices, here is one example:

```py
n = len(x_1g)
n2 = round(n/10)

ints1 = np.arange(n)  # generating an array [0 ... n-1]
np.random.shuffle(ints1)  # shuffle it
ints1 = ints1[:n2]  # take the first n2 values

x_1_replace = x_1g[ints1,:]
x_1 = np.delete(x_1g, ints1, 0)

x_2_replace = x_2g[ints1,:]
x_2 = np.delete(x_2g, ints1, 0)
```

Now you can check:

```py
x_1.shape
# (1352685, 10)
```

Comment: @yeoldnoobe thank you that has solved my issue, I didn't think about duplications!